# Jquery post response not available

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, post

I'm new to javascript, and this problem may be trivial but I need help.
My goal is to send a post to a python server based on tornado.

In the following function :

```
var machin = $.post( '/room/testroom', function( data ) {
         truc = data;
         return truc;
```

I never get back the content of `truc`.
This variable has an url inside it who will be used to create a new Websocket connection.

When I do `console.dir(machin);` I see the wanted `responseText` with the wanted url in the console, but I'm not able to get it outside of the console.

The variable data itself inside the function has my wanted data, as if I do :
    `alert(data)`
I see an alert box with the wanted url.

Feel free to ask me for details as I may not be entirely clear.

Server side, my python code is this one:

```
def post(self, RoomName):
    print 'je poste'
    db = connect(host=config.SQLSERVER, user=config.SQLUSER, passwd=config.SQLPASS, db=config.SQLDB)
    cursor = db.cursor()
    uri = self.request.uri
    url = uri.split('/')
    RoomName = url[2]
    sql = 'SELECT RoomID FROM abcd_un WHERE RoomName = %s', [RoomName]
    cursor.execute(*sql)
    RoomID = cursor.fetchone()
    print 'RoomID', type(RoomID)
    RoomID = str(RoomID[0])
    RoomID = RoomID.decode()
    fullurl = 'ws://' + self.request.host + '/socket/' + RoomID

    #print uri
    db.close()
    wsurl = {
        'url': fullurl,
    }
    wsurl_encoded = tornado.escape.json_encode(wsurl)
    self.write(wsurl_encoded)
```

Comment: Question edited to refleched change on server side code for JSON encoding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
var machin = function (){
     $.post( '/room/testroom', function( data ) {
     truc = JSON.parse(data);
     return truc;
}
```

Now call the function:

```
var response = machin();
```

Comment: The server answer was not intended to be JSON formatted at first, but give me a few moments please, i will modify the server side code then test that :)

Comment: Yes :) , use can use jsonify to return the data in JSON format.

Comment: But how did i get the answer outside inside the variable machin, now?

Comment: Took the edited code, but i may have something done wrong, when i do console.log(response) inside the code, the variable return undefined, no error, just undefined

Comment: Please tell me what exactly you are getting from server (by doing console.dir(machin);)

Comment: console.dir(machin); returns:  
   function machin()  
   arguemtns : null  
   caller: null  
   length: 0  
   name: "machin"

Comment: Hum... a tcpdump later... looks like that my frontend nginx decided to send back the answer gziped. this is out of the scope of this question. thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```js
var machin;
$.post( '/room/testroom', function( data ) {
     machin = JSON.parse(data);
     return True;
})
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer, but looks like i still have a problem, machin returns undefined when i check for it with console.log(machin)